# PHP code in html

Tags: php, html

I have absolutely no back around in PHP, so pardon me if I sound stupid.

I am trying to implement a login fucntion but i couldnt get the php part to work. is there any where wrong with write the code before the html tag? please kindly advise.

```
<?php
require "config.php";
$LS->init();
    if(isset($_POST['act_login'])){
 $user=$_POST['login'];
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 if($user=="" || $pass==""){
  $msg=array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
 }else{
  if(!$LS->login($user, $pass)){
   $msg=array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
  }
 }
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Log In</title>
 </head>
 <body>
normal html code.
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about. There are no form elements to support your question, nor otherwise.

Comment: What is $LS? Where do you declare it? What exactly isn't working about it? Is it not logging you in? What is the expected behavior? The point is, you give very little information and don't give us a ton to work with here.

Comment: *"PHP code in html"* - Blind stab at the question. Is your file holding the `.php` extension? Are you running this locally or on a hosted service? If local; is a web server installed, complete with PHP/Apache/MySQL and properly configured?

Comment: I wonder if you tried my answer and it was useful or you require more help? Let me know to improve the answer if needed !

Answer (score -1):

Ok, user2760642, I have fixed your code a little for what you had missing :

```
<?php
include_once "SOMECLASS.PHP";
$LS = new SOME_CLASS(); // CONTAINS METHOD TO CHECK LOGIN-PASS.
if(IsSet($_POST['login'])){ // CHECK IF USER CLICKED ENTER BUTTON.
 $user=$_POST['login'];
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 if($user=="" || $pass==""){
  echo "Error : Username / Password Wrong !";
 }else{
  if(!$LS->login($user, $pass)){
   echo "Error : Username / Password Wrong !";
  }else{
   header("Location:mainpage.php"); // OPENS THE MAIN PAGE BECAUSE
  }                                 // LOGIN-PASS WERE ALL RIGHT.
 }
}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Log In</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<form method="post" action="loginpage.php">
  Login <input type="text" name="login" />
  <br/>
  Password <input type="text" name="pass" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Click here to ENTER" />
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

It is wrong to add the PHP code in the same HTML file because if user presses BACK button the previous page would reload and the PHP code would be re-executed (it wouldn't happen with a separated php script file). You were missing the form asking the login and password. Finally, I added the class to check the login and password in the database (SOMECLASS.PHP).

You can copy and paste this code to a textfile named loginpage.php, and save it to the www subdirectory inside you wamp (or lamp or mamp) directory. Then just run it from address bar of your browser with localhost/loginpage.php. If it doesn't run, try localhost:80/loginpage.php (if it stills not running, call Houston because we have a problem).

I hope it helps you learning PHP.